# Cocoapods + storyboard + images

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

So what I'm trying to do is put a component used across couple of apps as a private cocoapod. It has a storyboard, and couple of images with @1x and @2x versions. Storyboard uses those images in UIImageViews.

Works fine if images are placed as plain resources (not as part of an Asset library).

If images are located within an Asset Library - in IB the images shows fine, however app crashes during runtime when that scene loads, and it complains it can't see the images. Any ideas how to fix that?

--- UPD

I have resource specified like this in the podspec: `s.resource_bundle = { 'PodResources' => 'Pod/resource/*.*' }`. It copies images in separate bundle `PodResources`; images are just copied, and Asset Libraries are compiled into .car file.

Comment: You need the podspec to copy the assets in a specific directory.

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @swalkner no, I've just worked that around

Comment: What's the workaround then?

Comment: @mllm nothing you'd be interested in - I've just integrated that manually instead of using cocoapod. Or you can include images as plain resources.